# Bootstrap: a row in a col-lg-* in a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I would like to have a row (in blue) in a col-lg-4 div (in red) in another row (in yellow), like this:

[image]

Here is what I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>


<div class="container-fluid" style="height: 400px;background-color: yellow">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1" style="background-color: red;">

            <div class="row" style="padding-top:20%;padding-bottom: 20%;background-color: blue;">
                dddd
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

with this css:

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    background-color: white;
}

.row1 {
    background: url("appart.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 400px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


[class*="col-"], footer {

  background-color: lightgreen;

  opacity: 0.5;

  line-height: 400px;

  text-align: center;

}
```

But I get this:

[image]

Despite that the colors get mixed up (if you have a solution to prevent this also It would be cool) I can't have the result that I am looking for...

much thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the jsfiddle code with the solution

In your css remove the class attribute rule [class*="col-"].Try targeting the rules to the specific elements using css. You are converting all the columns to have a line-height of 400px that's why your final html looks like that. And Don't use inline styles

If you remove the [class*="col-"] and add the following in the css file you will get the desired result

```
.container-fluid > .row, .col-lg-4.col-lg-offset-1 {
  height: 100%;
}

.col-lg-4.col-lg-offset-1 > .row {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Fiddle demo
https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/4js3r3hd/